# Search with tags using includes()

Tags: javascript

So I'm working in an application that uses tags as a search filter. but, I can't get a result while using two tags. for example, a store called CoffeShop has two tags 'Coffee' and 'Cookies'. when passing one of them it returns CoffeShop, but when passing both tags it returns nothing.

I tried using loadash and a few other things but none worked so far.

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "CoffeShop",
    "tag":[
      "Coffee",
      "Cookies",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "TeaShop",
    "tag":[
      "Tea",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "IceCreamShop",
    "tag": [
      "Ice Cream",
    ]
  },
]



let tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies']   
result = array.filter(item => item.tag.some(t =>  t.includes(tags)))
console.log(result)
```

The actual result should give me back only one store which is `CoffeShop`, but i'm getting nothing

Comment: If you still prefer to use `array.some(func)`. You can use `array.filter(item => item.tag.some(checkTag)).map(item => item.name)`.

Comment: Write a function named `checkTag(tag)` with 1 statement `return tags.indexOf(tag) > -1`. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will look for an array within your tags, it will not automatically check all values in the array for you. You can do the following:

```
result = array.filter(item => tags.every(tag => item.tag.includes(tag)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse include should be **Array**.include(**item**)

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "CoffeShop",
    "tag":[
      "Coffee",
      "Cookies",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "TeaShop",
    "tag":[
      "Tea",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "IceCreamShop",
    "tag": [
      "Ice Cream",
    ]
  },
]



let tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies']  

result = array.filter(item => item.tag.some(t =>  tags.includes(t)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "CoffeShop",
    "tag":[
      "Coffee",
      "Cookies",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "TeaShop",
    "tag":[
      "Tea",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "IceCreamShop",
    "tag": [
      "Ice Cream",
    ]
  },
]
const _strip = str => str.replace(/\s/g, '')
const _minimize = arr => arr.map(t => _strip(t.toLowerCase()))

const getShopWithTags = (shops = [], tags = []) => {
  tags = _minimize(tags)
  return array.filter(({tag}) => tags.includes(..._minimize(tag)))
}

let tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies']  
let result = getShopWithTags(array, tags)
console.log(result)

tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies', 'Ice Cream']
result = getShopWithTags(array, tags)
console.log(result)
```

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "CoffeShop",
    "tag":[
      "Coffee",
      "Cookies",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "TeaShop",
    "tag":[
      "Tea",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "IceCreamShop",
    "tag": [
      "Ice Cream",
    ]
  },
]

let tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies']  
let result = array.filter(({tag}) => tags.includes(...tag))
console.log(result)

tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies', 'Ice Cream']
result = array.filter(({tag}) => tags.includes(...tag))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like `tags.includes(t)`. in your code you just reversed the includes, it should be `Array.include(item)`

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "CoffeShop",
    "tag":[
      "Coffee",
      "Cookies",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "TeaShop",
    "tag":[
      "Tea",
    ],
  },
   {
    "name": "IceCreamShop",
    "tag": [
      "Ice Cream",
    ]
  },
]



let tags = ['Coffee', 'Cookies']   
result = array.filter(item => item.tag.some(t =>  tags.includes(t)))
console.log(result)
```